# Mariadb Aborted connection error without user name

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-grant

In MariaDB I am having this warning in the error log. Is there a way to resolve the issue without knowing the user name?

```
[Warning] Aborted connection 1101 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '127.0.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

Comment: you can enable audit logs to track further about connections

Comment: I've had this happen with SSL connections because the user was connecting to the host as IP address instead of using its hostname...

Comment: I've also had this happen when someone tries to connect to the db with ssl enabled but using the wrong CA/cert/key for their client when using 2 way encryption with self signed certs. The connection might look something like this when using the command line `mysql -u root -p -h mysite.com --protocol=TCP --ssl-ca=/pathto/client-ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/pathto/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/pathto/client-key.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert`

Answer (score 2):

This is a user killing a connection before it negotiated to a user.

Unless you know what users executed mysql on the server at that exact time there's not much to track this down. Even if you did find a user, asking them to fully authenticate seems rather pointless.

Comment: Update: From [MDEV-12274](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12274) newer MariaDB versions won't log this noise as a warning.